# How to call to ASMX web services SOAP with Python3.6 SUDS

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap

### There is a simple code block which isn't working:

```
import suds
from suds.client import Client
url="http://XX.XX.XX.XX:yy/webservice.asmx"
client=suds.client.Client(url)
```

---

errors are following:

```
  "D:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" D:/PycharmProjects/work/abc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 180, column 16

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\abc.py", line 5, in <module>
client=suds.client.Client(url)
File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 115,   in __init__
self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 150, in open
d = self.fn(url, self.options)


.......

xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:180:16: mismatched tag
```

Process finished with exit code 1

---

win 10

### py3.6

Could anyone help me?thanks.

````

Comment: You didn't close the quotation after the url.

Comment: Thanks,I lost one quotation and now I add it in the end of line

Answer (score 2):

Done, I used zeep while giving up suds, and then solved it myself

```
from zeep import Client
AOurl="http://xyz.asmx"
client = Client("http://xyz.asmx?WSDL")
f = open('2.xml','rt',encoding='GB2312')
s=f.read()
response=client.service.DEMO1(s)
print(response)
f.close()
```